# Conservation of energy when slowing an object down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

If it takes energy to slow an object down, and then the object also loses KE, then how is energy conserved? Don't you have a net loss of energy?

Comment: The energy of a system isn’t conserved when an external force does work on it.

Comment: You could have asked a similar question when an object speeds up. The gain in energy is equal to the work done by the force applied to it.

Comment: It doesn't take energy to slow an object down. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Usually, you need to take into account something else like Newton's third law or friction. For example, in a frictionless environment when you slow down an object by pushing on it, you are pushed by the object, and then you are the one with kinetic energy now. So energy is merely transferred in that case. Newton's third law is actually very important to take into account in these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***If it takes energy to slow an object down, and then the object also loses KE, then how is energy conserved? Don't you have a net loss of energy?***

You never have a "loss" of energy. It is always conserved. It may just change its form. In order to slow the object down it takes negative work that takes the kinetic energy away from the object and does something with it.

That negative work could be dry friction work between surfaces in which case the loss of kinetic energy increases the temperature of the surfaces (their internal energy). Friction force opposes motion so the work is negative. Then the higher temperature surfaces can transfer heat to the lower temperature surroundings. Then it becomes the internal energy of the surroundings, etc.,etc.. If you follow all the energy transfers you realize the energy is never "lost" but simply morphs into different forms.

If you throw an object up in the air it slows down due to the force of gravity. Gravity does negative work (its force is also in the opposite direction to the motion). But in this case it takes the kinetic energy away from the object and gives it gravitational potential energy. When it starts falling down gravity does positive work on the object converting its gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy. If this is done in a vacuum, mechanical energy (kinetic plus potential) is conserved. If there is air drag, then once again some kinetic energy is lost due to air friction again eventually as heat and eventually becoming another form. But again, the energy is not "lost".

Hope this helps.

Comment: But an object slowing down in one frame of reference is speeding up in a moving frame of reference. In a moving frame of reference how can kinetic energy be transformed into heat by friction, if the object is also speeding up - this would increase heat and speed, increasing the total amount of energy ?

Comment: @Falco "But an object slowing down in one frame of reference is speeding up in a moving frame of reference" Sorry, but I'm afraid I don't understand this statement. Could you elaborate on it? Perhaps an example?

Comment: Yes. Imagine an asteroid flying though a cloud. From a stationary reference frame of the cloud the asteroid will hit the cloud, create friction, heat and slow down. So the kinetic energy is transferred into heat energy. From the perspective of a rocket flying besides the asteroid (a reference frame with the same initial speed as the asteroid) the asteroid is standing still and the cloud is approaching with high speed and hits the asteroid. And the asteroid is accelerated by this hit away from the rocket, still creating the same heat from friction.

Comment: @Falco I need clarification on several points. Let’s begin with the statement “From a stationary reference frame of the cloud the asteroid will hit the cloud, create friction, heat and slow down”.  By “stationary reference frame of the cloud” are you referring to the reference frame of the cloud, or a separate reference that is initially stationary with respect to the cloud, as the rocket is initially with respect to the asteroid?

Comment: @Falco Do you understand that once the asteroid enters the cloud the cloud is no longer "stationary"?

Comment: As far as I understand for conservation of energy to hold true the reference frames should not change velocity. So both reference frames will have constant velocity - one will have the starting velocity of the cloud and the other starting velocity of the asteroid. If the asteroid imparts some of its momentum onto the cloud then the cloud will be slowly moving from the first reference frame, whereas the asteroid will considerably slow down. From the second reference frame the cloud will approach very fast and fly by, slowing down a little on contact with the asteroid.

Comment: ... while the asteroid will be heavily accelerated on contact with the cloud (as seen from the second reference frame, which keeps moving with the initial speed of the asteroid) The rocket is not part of any physical interactions, it was just to illustrate where an observer with the second reference frame might stand. From both reference frames there is a collision between cloud and asteroid, an exchange of momentum and energy released as heat. But with one the overall kinetic energy in the system seems to increase.

Comment: @Falco Velocity and kinetic energy are reference frame dependent. What’s more kinetic energy is not a conserved quantity. Only total energy. With regard to the rest of your statements, I’m afraid I can’t figure out which reference frames you are referring to. Here are the facts: Before the “collision” between the asteroid and the cloud, the asteroid, rocket and cloud are all inertial reference frames. DURING the collision, only the rocket is an inertial frame.

Comment: During the collision, in the rocket frame the asteroid speeds up but at the same time the cloud slows down. If I want to compare the interaction in another reference frame I would select another inertial frame.  For example, another asteroid that is not part of the cloud but is stationary with respect to the cloud before the collision. In that frame the moving asteroid slows down and the cloud speeds up. In both frames the asteroid/cloud momentum is conserved. Kinetic energy is not.

Comment: Okay I understand that the Cloud complicates everything. How about this simpler example: a single satellite with a solar sail in empty space. The solar sail is hit with light. In one reference frame the satellite will be speeding up in another reference frame it will be slowing down. In both reference frames the energy of the light is absorbed by the solar sail. But in one reference frame the kinetic energy of the satellite is increasing in the other reference frame the kinetic energy is decreasing. How is overall energy conserved in both cases?

Comment: And thank you for engaging my questions in the comments 

Comment: @Falco what are the two reference frames you’re talking about?

Comment: Just any two reference frames with different velocities in regard to the satellite. E.g. if the satellite is moving relative to a local star, one reference frame could be stationary in regards to the local star and the other reference frame could start out with the initial velocity of the satellite. In the first frame the satellite is moving towards the sun and slowed down bei the light hitting its solar sails. In the other reference frame the stallite seems stationary and is accelerated by the light.

Comment: @Falco "...the other reference frame could start out with the initial velocity of the satellite". What do you mean by "start out".? Is the other reference frame inertial? Are your two reference frames inertial?

Comment: I understand that the reference frames need to be inertial for conservation of energy to hold. So the reference frames have a fixed velocity.

Comment: @Falco  Conservation of total energy holds for an isolated system in any reference frame. Kinetic energy alone is reference frame dependent. In Galilean relativity acceleration is the same for all inertial frames. So if your solar sail is decelerating in one inertial frame it is decelerating in all inertial frames.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. From one perspective the satellite will be moving faster (accelerating) relative to the observer (aka reference frame) while from another observer it will be moving slower (decelerating).

Answer (score 0):

Energy conservation means the total energy of the system, which includes the object and the person who does the slowing down.

If the object has mass $m$ and moves with speed $v$ the kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ so that the person must supply this amount of energy to stop the object. This work supplied by the person may be supplied in a variety of approaches. For example, if they apply a constant force $F$ then the object will come to rest over a distance $d$ where $d$ is determined from $$F d = \frac{1}{2} m v^2.$$

Comment: It is quite the opposite, the object is doing work until it stops. If it is stopped by a person, there comes the biological aspect. The body spends energy for absorbing energy as work is being done on the body. The object kinetic energy and body chemical energy are converted mostly to thermal energy.